# How do you count the number of items in a list in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r

Example:

```
> df <- data.frame(a=1:2)
> df$b <- list(1:4, 5:10)
> df %<>% mutate(c = length(b))
> df       
  a                 b c
1 1        1, 2, 3, 4 2
2 2 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 2
```

I was expecting:

```
  a                 b c
1 1        1, 2, 3, 4 4
2 2 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 6
```

How do I call length(b) correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`length` get the `length` of the whole `list` i.e. 2 or the number of rows.  Here, we need to add `s` as suffix i.e. `lengths` to return the length of each individual `list` element

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
df %<>%
    mutate(c = lengths(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using mapply:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(a=1:2)
df$b <- list(1:4, 5:10)
df$c=mapply(length,df$b)
```